# differentiate between different in app purchases iphone paymentQueue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have just managed to integrate in app purchases into my ios application however i have know run into a problem that i can't really ask google about.

I have an app with 2 products to purchase but once payment is complete i need to differentiate between the 2 products purchased to then fire another method.

please see the paymentQueue method below:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
    {
        for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
        {
            switch(transaction.transactionState) {
                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                    //do crediting here
                    NSLog(@"transactionid = %@",transaction);
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                    if(transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Error Encountered");
                    }

                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

When the `SKPaymentStatePurchased` is hit it needs to find the initial product that was purchased to then fire the method for the product to credit an account set up on a remote server.

I hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that from the transaction itself

```
transaction.payment.productIdentifier
```

This will give you the product identifier that the user have purchased